# Change SQL query of split form and refresh to get new result

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I want to change the SQL of a split form in Ms Access

```
Dim db As Database
Dim query As QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set query = db.QueryDefs("MyQuery")

Me.query = query.SQL
Me.Requery
```

Now the operation `Me.query = query.SQL` works, I have checked it but it simply does not refresh the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you mean to set the recordsource:

```
Me.recordsource = query.SQL
```

As an aside, I would be cautious about using object names for variable names, `query` is not a good name for a variable.

Comment: I tried that before, but there was no change. But thanks, generally you are right, I will change it to requery in the question.

Comment: OK, so your solution was right after all, there was a problem with using a split form in ms access. Thanks!